# Rails 4: pass parent belongs_to attributes to children

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, trailblazer

To put my question in context, I have a form that has many fields. Each field can be at the root or a children of another field (hierarchy using Closure Table in my database). I don't have any problem building the hierarchies table, but I have a problem setting the `form_id` on the children fields.

Here is my schema:

```
create_table "fields", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer  "form_id", null: false
    [...]
    t.integer  "parent_id"
end
```

And my models (stripped down for simplicity):

```
class Field < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :fields,
             foreign_key: :parent_id,
             inverse_of: :field,
             dependent: :destroy

    belongs_to :form, inverse_of: :fields, touch: true
    belongs_to :field,
               foreign_key: :parent_id,
               inverse_of: :fields
end

class Form < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :fields,
             inverse_of: :form,
             dependent: :destroy
end
```

If I save my children fields using nested form, I get this error: `ERROR:  null value in column "form_id" violates not-null constraint`. The `form_id` is not passed if I do: `Form.find(1).fields.first.fields.new` for example.

Is there a way to set this automatically? The `parent_id` is set automatically.

*EDIT*

Example of the `params` stack. I use Trailblazer architecture with Reform.

```
{
    [...]
    "fields"=>[{
        "id"=>"11",
        "_destroy"=>"false",
        "position"=>"1",
        "value"=>"Foobar",
        "fields"=>[{
            "id"=>"",
            "_destroy"=>"false",
            "position"=>"1",
            "value"=>"Foobar child"
        }]
    }]
}
```

Comment: interesting, last time I saw something like this was in drupal's database, first of first, i think it's better to name `:fields` to `:children_fields` and `:field` to `:parent_field` to understand them better. since you want the `:form_id` of the parent field to be passed down to the `children_fields`, can't you just initialize them from the start? Or create a `before_create` to set it?

Comment: I prefer to keep it `fields` only, but this is mostly personal to this point... I understand that is it easier to understand though! I don't want to use `before_create` or any other triggers if it is possible since I'm using the Trailblazer stack with Reform contracts. I want to use less automagick things and I want to keep my model very thin for separation of concerns. Even with the `before_create`, it will have to query back the parent when you do `field.form_id`?

Comment: can we see the nested form for the children fields? also some codes from the controller action would be nice too

Comment: @lusketeer I added an example of `params`, but I don't think it is useful for this question... Like I said, this: `Form.find(1).fields.first.fields.new({...})` doesn't pass `form_id` so it will not pass either if my params doesn't have `form_id` (which I will not pass from a form in which a user can edit any datas for security reason). Any other idea?

Comment: why cant you just set the form_id to `@form.id` in your controller action?

Comment: @lusketeer `params[:form_id]` if set at the root of the `params` with the routes (if it is in edit mode), but it is not set inside the `fields`. I will have to loop through the `params` and set it. The reality is that I can create form and fields at the same time so the form id doesn't exist sometime. The `before_create` works perfectly for that case, but I was wondering if there was another approach! Thanks for your help

Comment: yea no worries, sorry can't be more helpful, good luck